# How do I store XP_SMTP mail result code messages?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am trying to keep a record of all of the emails that get sent via xp_smtp mail component, but I don't know how to store the message. Storing a 1 because it failed doesn't do me much good.

```
DECLARE @rc INT
EXEC @rc = master.dbo.xp_smtp_sendmail...

--Once the email is sent put the results (pass or fail) into another table:
EXEC pr_InsertEmailLog  @Body, @From, @Subject, @To, @rc, 'Error MESSAGE here'
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://sqldev.net/xp/xpsmtp.htm#Return_codes) say it only returns 0 or 1.

However, [further down](http://sqldev.net/xp/xpsmtp.htm#Planned_functionality_enhancements) it mentions planned work with an output message parameter

> Add an output parameter (@errmsg
>   OUTPUT) which contains the error
>   message in case of a failure to have
>   better control over the execution and
>   enable to XP to work in complete
>   silent mode. The parameter would only
>   contain data if the return code of the
>   XP is not equal to 0 (zero) indicating
>   some sort of failure.

YMMV, but some kind soul may have developed it further then this release.